# Vuex Mutating a state variable not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to update my contacts when a different brand is selected. When I select a new brand, the contacts should be updated. So I clear my array of the contacts of the brand and then fill it again.

Somehow though, the clearing of the array doesn't work in my Vuex setup. Is there anyone who knows why?

This is my Store file:

```
export default {
    state: {
        brands: Array(), //Might be used later on, if not, remove.
        brandsForDropdown: Array(),
        brandContactsForDropdown: Array(),
    },
    getters: {
      brands: state => {
        return state.brands;
      },
      brandsForDropdown: state => {
        return state.brandsForDropdown
      },
      brandContactsForDropdown: state => {
        return state.brandContactsForDropdown
      }
    },
    actions: {
        getBrands({state, commit}) {
            Vue.http.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_SERVER + '/brands').then(response => {
                if(response.body.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.body.length; i++) { 
                        commit('pushBrands', {"name" : response.body[i].name, "value" : response.body[i].id})
                    }
                }
              }, response => {
                // error callback
              });
        },
        getBrandContacts({state, commit}, payload) {
            //commit('resetBrandContacts')
            Vue.http.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_SERVER + '/brands/contacts/' + payload.value).then(response => {
                if(response.body.length > 0) {
                    let newArray = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.body.length; i++) { 
                        newArray.push({"name" : response.body[i].firstname + " " + response.body[i].surname, "value" : response.body[i].id})
                    }
                    commit('pushBrandContact', newArray)
                }
              }, response => {
                // error callback
              });
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        pushBrands(state, payload) {
            state.brandsForDropdown.push(payload)
        },
        resetBrands(state) {
            state.brandsForDropdown = []
        },
        resetBrandContacts(state) {
            state.brandContactsForDropdown = []
        },
        pushBrandContact(state, payload) {
            console.log(payload)
            state.brandContactsForDropdown = payload
            console.log(state.brandContactsForDropdown)
        }
    }
}
```

This is my full component code:

```
<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      productName: null,
      productBrand: null,
      brands: this.$store.getters.brandsForDropdown,
      selectedBrand: null,
      brandContacts: this.$store.getters.brandContactsForDropdown,
      selectedContacts: null,
    }
  },
  computed: {
  },
  watch: {
      selectedBrand: function() {
          if(this.selectedBrand != null) {
              this.$store.dispatch('getBrandContacts', this.selectedBrand)
              //this.brandContacts = this.$store.getters.brandContactsForDropdown
          }
          console.log(this.brandContacts);
      }
  },
  methods: {
  },
  mounted: function() {
  this.$store.dispatch('getBrands')
  }
}
</script>
```

And up there is my full Vuex module.

Comment: Is that last line in the `data` method of a component? Because if so, `brandContacts` is only getting set once on the component's initialization, and you would need to make `brandContacts` a computed property instead in order for it to reflect any changes to the value of `this.$store.getters.brandContactsForDropdown`.

Comment: The last line is in the data method of my Vue component. It's weird how another value I set IS updated when it changes in Vuex...

Comment: Yeah, without seeing that code it's hard to know what would cause that.

Comment: Added the code, hope you can find what's wrong :)

Comment: So I'm assuming the `brands` property is the one you said is getting updated when  it changes in vuex. But where is that code?

Comment: Yes that is true. That code is just the same as the getBrandContacts, just without the reset commit at the start. Somehow the reset is destroying the whole state.

Comment: Edited the question. It now has both the files in full.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you reached one of the [Gotchas](https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/):

I'm not sure if this is the case where you update the array and it will not detect the change, but the best way to update the array would be to place a new array instead of adding to it:

```
getBrandContacts({state, commit}, payload) {
  Vue.http.get(process.env.VUE_APP_API_SERVER + '/brands/contacts/' + 
               payload.value).then(response => {
    if(response.body.length > 0) {
      let newArray = []
      for (var i = 0; i < response.body.length; i++) { 
        newArray.push({"name" : 
                       response.body[i].firstname + " " + response.body[i].surname, "value" : 
                       response.body[i].id})
      }
      commit('pushBrandContact', newArray)
    }
  }, response => {
    // error callback
  });
}
```

and in mutations:

```
pushBrandContact(state, payload) {
  state.brandContactsForDropdown = payload
}
```

It is also not clear how you work with the data inside the component, is it a data? or in computed? sharing this code will help.
You also say the array doesn't clear, what you mean? it have the old values? in the vuex state? on in your component? a lot of info to help is missing.

**Update**

The data properties are getting updated only on init of the component, and when you manually update it (`this.data = newData`), they will not be updated when Vuex is updated.

You need to move the `brandContacts: this.$store.getters.brandContactsForDropdown` from the data object to the computed object like this:
`brandContacts(){ this.$store.state.brandContactsForDropdown }`

This will force vue to update when the `brandContactsForDropdown` property in vuex updates.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: The last line is in the data() of my component. What I mean with the array doesn't clear is that I push contacts to the array, but when a new brand is selected, I want to clear the array to make room for the new contacts of the new brand.

The Vuex state should just be cleared, but it seems like it isn't.

Comment: have you tried to replace the whole array as in my answer? did it have the same effect? have you tried moving the line to the computed and set it like this: `brandContacts: this.$store.state.brandContactsForDropdown`

Comment: I just tried, It seems like the mutation just doesn't want to work.

Comment: The result is just an empty array, like it's initialized.

Comment: how do you know the array is empty? where do you see it?

Comment: I just console.logged my state after I put in the payload. And the state has the payload inside itself, so that works fine.

When I console.log the brandContacts value in my component after the watch function has fired however, the brandContacts is empty.

Comment: Can you update your question with the console.logs you added? just so i just can understand exactly where it is empty

Comment: Ah, that seems to be the case ^^ Thanks for your help! May I ask you one more question though, how do i get the length of a computer property? v-else-if="brandContacts.length == 0" doesn't seem to work now.

Comment: the computed property behave the same as the data property, you can .length on it and see the length of the array.

Comment: I wonder why its not working for you @Danoctum, this works fine for me `<div v-html="(testData.length === 11")></div>`, what does it shows? errors?

Comment: Check your naming, make sure its all the same and don't forget that the computed property is updated according to the vuex, so it will reflect the vuex state, and computed property can't be defined in other objects (data or methods).